# Xubuntu 21.04 freezes randomly

Tags: kernel, xubuntu, amd-graphics, radeon

**A desktop PC freezes totally** (mouse and keyboard both stop working absolutely, SysRq key doesn't work too) one time per two-three days when using stock Xubuntu 21.04 kernel (5.11.0-25-generic and 5.11.0-31-generic were tested) and one time per month when using PPA kernel (5.13.9-051309-generic was tested).

**A visual artefact occurs always**: after an user logins through GDM the screen splashes and displays for about 2 seconds white field with a lot of RGB-colored  randomly placed dots. Then a graphical desktop appears and the system works well (web browsing mostly) up to the freeze. After "cold restart" the system using power button this artefact looks like screenshot of the system desktop at the point of the freeze (and this is very strange: where it come from?).

**Some information about the PC:**

- Motherboard: BIOSTAR R690A-M2T (Phoenix BIOS v.6.00 PG)
- CPU: AMD Sempron LE-1300, socket AM2
- RAM: DDR2, 2048 MiB
- Graphics: built-in AMD690G chipset (family R400, engineering name RS690, marketing name X1250), monitor connected using VGA interface.
- HDD: IDE 160 GiB Seagate, swap partition 2 GiB.

**Additional information about the graphics subsystem** (inxi -G):

> Device-1: AMD RS690 [Radeon X1200] driver: radeon v: kernel
> Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: ati,radeon    unloaded:
> fbdev,modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz    OpenGL: renderer:
> ATI RS690 v: 2.1 Mesa 21.0.3

**These tries to tune kernel don't solve the problem**:

- ... trace_clock=local nr_cpus=1
- ... radeon.dpm=0 pcie=noaer

**This try to disable any GPU acceleration doesn't solve the problem**:
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-radeon.conf:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Radeon"
    Driver "radeon"
    Option "NoAccel" "true"
    Option "DRI" "false"
EndSection
```

*Does anyone have suggestion how to solve the freeze and the artefact troubles?*